# Transpose columns into rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

need help configuring the query below:

Query1:

```
SELECT  @s:= @s + 1 serial_number,`COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`, (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='2014rawfiles' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='012014actives';
```

Query1 output:

```
|  serial_number  |  COLUMN_NAME  |
|        1        |      ID       |
|        2        |   FirstName   |
|        3        |   LastName    |
   ... up to 89 rows ...
```

I am trying to transpose the output of this query to look like this:

```
|  1  |      2      |     3     |
| ID  |  FirstName  | LastName  |
```

with the serial_number as header and the COLUMN_NAME as a single row. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this you can do it with dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''',column_name, ''' `', @n := @n + 1, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM information_schema.columns CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND table_name = '012014actives'
 ORDER BY ordinal_position;    

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|  1 |         2 |        3 |
|----|-----------|----------|
| Id | FirstName | LastName |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3070ed/8)** demo

Comment: @mfrancisp You're quite welcome. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this.But you can choose an alternate for this which I am going to tell
 you.

you can not split values to column but can merge them in a single column and can further split them into your front end.

SELECT group_concat(serial_number) from pivot  union all SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) from
  pivot

by this you will get result like this

1,2,3

ID, FirstName, LastName